# NodeJS Express Module Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'finished' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, selenium, express

I'm trying to make an api that gets the text from a site from whatever words you put. I used selenium to load the site up and send the text but I can't send it back. Here's my code:

```
app.get("/search/:data", function(req, res){
async function extraction(){
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type='text'])[6]")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type='text'])[6]")).sendKeys(req.params.data.replaceAll('_', ' '));
    console.log(`Sent keys ${req.params.data} from ${req.ip}.`);
    setTimeout(function () {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div[1]/div")).getText().then(res.write);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div[2]/div")).getText().then(res.write);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div[3]/div")).getText().then(res.write);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div[4]/div")).getText().then(res.write);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div[5]/div")).getText().then(res.write);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div[6]/div")).getText().then(res.write);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div[7]/div")).getText().then(res.write);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div[8]/div")).getText().then(res.write);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div[9]/div")).getText().then(res.write);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div[10]/div")).getText().then(res.write);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div[11]/div")).getText().then(res.write);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div[12]/div")).getText().then(res.write);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div[13]/div")).getText().then(res.write);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div[14]/div")).getText().then(res.write);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div[15]/div")).getText().then(res.write);
            res.end();
        }, 10000);

}
extraction();
});
```

When I replace res.write with console.log it logs it but I just can't get it to send. I'm new to Javascript so I'm still learning, I have spent hours searching for an answer but can't get it to work.

Error message:

````
  if (msg.finished) {
          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'finished' of undefined
    at write_ (node:_http_outgoing:727:11)
    at write (node:_http_outgoing:687:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5)```
````

Comment: the error message and the code doen't have any relation , please add the code which throws that error

Comment: the code that makes the error then is probably in the express module or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you can't pass `res.write` as callback, because it looses track of the response object, where it tries to read the `finished` property from.

Try by creating a custom callback that calls `res.write`, e.g.

```js
const writeToResponse = res.write.bind(res);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div[1]/div")).getText().then(writeToResponse);
// similarly the rest of the code
```

Apart from the above fix, I see more potential problems with the code in current structure:
As far as I remember, `.getText` returns a promise, so we're dealing with asynchronous code here.

1. You're calling `res.end()` without waiting for the preceding instructions to finish. This will most likely lead to following error

```
Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end
```

You should probably [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) each call or all together using [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

2. If order in which texts are written to the response is important, then you should await each call before executing the next, otherwise all 15 calls execute in parallel and race with writing data to response.